# add a column with different label

Tags: linux

I want to add a column that contains two different labels. Let's say I have this text

```
aa bb cc 
dd ee ff
gg hh ii
ll mm nn
oo pp qq
```

and I want to add 1 at hte first column of the first two lines and 2 at the first column of the remaining lines, so that eventually I will get that text:

```
1 aa bb cc
1 dd ee ff
2 gg hh ii
3 ll mm nn
4 oo pp qq
```

Do you know how to do it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to do this using the shell, if your data is in a file called `input.txt`, you can either use `cat -n` or `nl`.

```
% tail -n+2 input.txt | cat -n
     1  dd ee ff
     2  gg hh ii
     3  ll mm nn
     4  oo pp qq
% tail -n+2 input.txt | nl 
     1  dd ee ff
     2  gg hh ii
     3  ll mm nn
     4  oo pp qq
```

The first line can be added back manually.

The two commands will behave differently if you have empty lines in your input file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are processing a text file in Linux shell, you could use `awk` for this. Your problem description says you want two labels `1` and `2`, this would be

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print (NR<=2 ? "1 ":"2 ") $0}'
```

Your expected output says you want label `1` for the first two lines, and start counting from `2` beginning with the third line, this would be

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print (NR<=2 ? "1 ":NR-1" ") $0}'
```

Comment: IMHO you need not to use cat with awk, as awk could read Input_file by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

**Solution 1st:** By using a variable named count whose initial value is 1 and then checking if line number is either 1 or 2 then simply append 1 in $1 else increase variable count's value by 1 and append it in $1's value.

```
awk -v count=1 '{$1=NR==1||NR==2?1 FS $1:++count FS $1} 1'   Input_file
```

**Solution 2nd:** Checking if line number is 1 or 2 then simply adding 1 to $1 else checking if a line is NOT NULL then add NR-1(which means subtract 1 from it's line number) and add to $1's value.

```
awk '{$1=NR==1||NR==2?1 FS $1:(NF?FNR-1 FS $1:"")} 1' Input_file
```